# Adding a new column to a DataFrame

Tags: r

I am trying to add a column for totals to a dataframe using R and am getting this error:

> Error in rowSums(EurostatCrime2017[, 7:10]) : 'x' must be numeric.

Here is my code:

```
EurostatCrime2017$All_Theft <- rowSums(EurostatCrime2017[,7:11])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be due to the `type` issue.  If we check the type of the columns with `str`

```
str(EurostatCrime2017[,7:10])
```

will find if the columns are not numeric or integers.

One option is to convert the columns to `numeric`

```
EurostatCrime2017[,7:10] <- lapply(EurostatCrime2017[,7:10], function(x)
         as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Here, we specified `as.character` in case the columns are `factor`.

and then do the `rowSums`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the options and it doesnt seem to be working. Here is a link to the document I am working on.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=193JI7z41xvpDh88MWrKp52I3HiQ76LFb